# Proof Verification: find the matrix representation for the operator $\frac {d}{dx}$ on the solution of the ODE $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> **Problem:** Find the matrix representation for the operator $\frac{d}{dx}\equiv D$ on the solution of the differential equation $~\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=0~$ and hence show that $~\text D^2~+~I=0~,$ where $~\text D~$ is the matrix representation of $\frac{d}{dx}$ and I is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

**My work:** Solution of the given differential equation is $~y=a\cos x ~+~b\sin x~,~$ where $~a~$ and $~b~$ are arbitrary independent constants.
Thus the two dimensional space V is generated by the basis $~\text B_\text{V}=\{\cos x,~\sin x\}~$ and the coordinate of any element in V relative to $~\text B_\text{V}~$ is given by $~[y]_{\text B_\text{V}}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}~.$
Now $~~~\frac{dy}{dx}=-a\sin x~+~b\cos x$

This space W (say) is generated by a basis $~\text B_\text{W}=\{\cos x,~\sin x\}~.$
The transformation $~\text D\colon\text V\to\text W~$ transforms $~y\in \text V~$ into $~\text D_y\in\text W~$ as
$$\text D_y\equiv\frac{dy}{dx}=-a\sin x~+~b\cos x=\begin{pmatrix} \cos x & \sin x \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b\\-a\end{pmatrix}~.$$
Then the matrix representation of $~\text D~,$  $$[\text Dy]_{\text B_\text{W}}=\text A~[\text y]_{\text B_\text{V}}$$
$$\implies \begin{pmatrix}b\\-a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta\\\gamma & \delta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\implies b=a\alpha~+~b\beta\qquad\text{and}\qquad -a=a\gamma~+~b\delta$$
$$\implies \alpha=0,~\beta=1,~\gamma=-1,~\delta=0$$(by comparing both sides the coefficients of $a$ and $b$).

So the matrix of the transformation D is $$[\text D]_{\text B_\text{V}}^{\text B_\text{W}}=\text A=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta\\\gamma & \delta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\equiv\text D\qquad(\text {say})$$

Therefore $$\text D^2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=-\text I\implies \text D^2~+~I=0~.$$

**Edit:** I made an edit according to the suggestion given by @TitoEliatron. So please verify my solution process. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is taht you haver CHANGE the order of the basis.

At the beginning, tha basis is $\{\cos x,\sin x\}$, but in the 5th line (beginnig at MY WORK) you write
$$\text D_y\equiv\frac{dy}{dx}=-a\sin x~+~b\cos x=\begin{pmatrix} \sin x & \cos x \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-a\\b\end{pmatrix}~.$$
But you should write

$$\text D_y\equiv\frac{dy}{dx}=-a\sin x~+~b\cos x=\begin{pmatrix} \cos x & \sin x \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b\\-a\end{pmatrix}~.$$.

With this correction, I think that you'll get $$D=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\cr1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ wich yields to $D^2=-I$.

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind this ? Then it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: The reason is that a BASIS is an ordered set. I mean. The vector with coordinates $(a,b)$ is $a\cos x+b\sin x$. So if you take the derivative, $-a\sin x+b\cos x$ it will converts into $b\cos x-a\sin x=(-b,a)$.

Comment: Is it $(-b,a)$ or $(b, -a)$ ?

Comment: $(b,-a)$, sorry